# How to create a dynamically-allocated array of const objects, but have values assigned to them?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constants, sfml

I need to create a dynamically-allocated array of const objects. What makes it difficult is that I need to have values assigned to the const objects too.

I need this for Samples variable of [this SFML class](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/structsf_1_1SoundStream_1_1Chunk.php#ac7a44423bcd7cf2c451f3bd1e00b6a9f).

How should I do it?

Comment: As @Mike Seymour figured out, you probably don't understand what you *need* correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an array of `const` objects. A pointer-to-const can point to either const or non-const objects; you can create a dynamic array and initialise a `Chunk` structure from it like this:

```
std::vector<Int16> samples;
initialise(samples);

// valid until 'samples' is destroyed or resized
SoundStream::Chunk chunk = {&samples[0], samples.size()};
```

Comment: Ahh, someone who read up the background to the OP's question ... and unsurprisingly discovered that the OP didn't know what she needed! +1 for that. (The Fundamental Problem of Life is seeing through what people say they want and discover what they *need*. I think the Rolling Stones figured that out way before usability analysts became popular.)

Comment: Thanks for this nice STL solution.

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
// Step 1: Make an array of const values:
const int arr[] = { 1, 4, 9, 17 };

// Step 2: Make a pointer to it:
auto        parr     = &arr; // 2011-style
const int (*pbrr)[4] = &arr; // old-style
```

You cannot "assign" values to constants (obviously), so the only way to endow a constant with a value is to *initialize* it to that value.

Comment: What is the purpose of the parenthesis around `*pbrr`? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I need the array to be dynamically-allocated.

Comment: Step 3: Profit! (sorry, old cliché)

Comment: @sim642: A dynamic array of constants is only possible in C++11, since you need uniform initialization to initialize it: `const int * p = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };`.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if the data is not known at compile time:

```
const std::vector<int> function() {
    std::vector<int> tmp(5); //make the array
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        tmp [i] = i; //fill the array
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you need a dynamically allocated array, I recommend using a standard container:

```
std::vector<Int16> data;
Chunk* c = ...;

data.push_back(...);

c->Samples = &data[0];
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I need the array to be dynamically-allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Do the allocation, assign it to a pointer to non-const.  Make your modifications to the data.  When you're done muckin' things about, then you can assign your const pointer to the array. For example:

```
int * p = new int[100];
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    p[i] = i;

const int * cp = p;
```